# wp_mail: An array as $to - multiple emails or single email with all the email ids in it?

Tags: wp-mail

If I will use an array of email IDs for $to parameter of wp_mail function, will it send different emails to all those email ids or will send one email with all the email ids as 'to'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use an array of recipients:

```
 * @param string|array $to Array or comma-separated list of email addresses to send message.
 * @param string $subject Email subject
 * @param string $message Message contents
 * @param string|array $headers Optional. Additional headers.
 * @param string|array $attachments Optional. Files to attach.
 * @return bool Whether the email contents were sent successfully.
 */
function wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers = '', $attachments = array() ) {

// …


    // Set destination addresses
    if ( !is_array( $to ) )
        $to = explode( ',', $to );

    foreach ( (array) $to as $recipient ) {
        try {
            // Break $recipient into name and address parts if in the format "Foo <bar@baz.com>"
            $recipient_name = '';
            if( preg_match( '/(.*)<(.+)>/', $recipient, $matches ) ) {
                if ( count( $matches ) == 3 ) {
                    $recipient_name = $matches[1];
                    $recipient = $matches[2];
                }
            }
            $phpmailer->AddAddress( $recipient, $recipient_name);
        } catch ( phpmailerException $e ) {
            continue;
        }
    }
```

To send different emails, you have to call `wp_mail()` multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for posting the code. It looks like it will send one email with all the email IDs as 'to'.