# Notification to Admin or Author upon new post

Tags: posts, publish, notifications

I am using a custom function with 'publish_post' hook for a notification to the author when the post has been published but the issue I am facing right now is that the notification is being sent out twice and as well when the post is updated. Here is how my function looks.

```
function authorNotification($post_id) {
   $post = get_post($post_id);
   $author = get_userdata($post->post_author);

   $message = "
      Hi ".$author->display_name.",
      New post, ".$post->post_title." has just been published at ".get_permalink( $post_id ).".
   ";
   wp_mail($author->user_email, "New Post Published", $message);
}
add_action('publish_post', 'authorNotification');
```

am I missing something here?

Comment: See also [this code example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/116298/73).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write your hook for `transition_post_status` action:

```
function authorNotification( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( $new_status == 'publish' && $old_status != 'publish' ) {
        $author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
        $message = "
            Hi ".$author->display_name.",
            New post, ".$post->post_title." has just been published at ".get_permalink( $post->ID ).".
        ";
        wp_mail($author->user_email, "New Post Published", $message);
    }
}
add_action('transition_post_status', 'authorNotification', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: that did a trick for duplicate notification but I am still receiving a notification when the post is updated. Any thoughts on that? Thanks

Comment: I have updated the snippet and it will work

Comment: That work. I am very new to WordPress so thanks a lot.